# Javascript replace part of string that have matched value

Tags: javascript, regex, lodash

I have this string and i need to remove the AND clause that match a value. Ex: `RHID = '540' AND SEQ LIKE '%44%' AND NR_DOCUMENTO LIKE '%999%'`

I need to remove `AND NR_DOCUMENTO LIKE '%999%'` if value is '%999%'.
I need to remove `AND SEQ LIKE '%44%'` if value is '%44%'.

Note: The AND query part is dynamic and may have different things so it is more like find the value and remove backwards to AND

Comment: have you tried my answer ? Did that work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
AND(?=(?:(?!AND).)*'%(?:44|999)%').*?LIKE\s+'%.*?%'
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/A7WhtD/1/)

```js
const regex = /AND(?=(?:(?!AND).)*'%(?:44|999)%').*?LIKE\s+'%.*?%'/gim;
const str = `'540' AND sEQ LIKE '%44%' AND NR_DOCUMENTO LIKE '%45%' AND bla bla bla LIKE '%999%'`;
const result = str.replace(regex,``);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: but this is more generic ... lets say we never know the string , only the value

Comment: more like find the value and remove backwards to AND

Comment: @LeonelMatiasDomingos your question wasn't clear at the first place, however I have updated the answer as per your comment

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var string = "RHID = '540' AND SEQ LIKE '%44%' AND NR_DOCUMENTO LIKE '%999%'";

function replaceIt (valueSEQ, valueLIKE) {
  return string.replace(" AND SEQ LIKE '%" + valueSEQ +"%'", "")
               .replace(" AND NR_DOCUMENTO LIKE '%" + valueLIKE + "%'", "");
}

console.log( replaceIt(44, 999) );
```

```js
    var string = "RHID = '540' AND SEQ LIKE '%44%' AND NR_DOCUMENTO LIKE '%999%'";
    
function replaceIt (valueSEQ, valueLIKE) {
    return string.replace(" AND SEQ LIKE '%" + valueSEQ +"%'", "")
                 .replace(" AND NR_DOCUMENTO LIKE '%" + valueLIKE + "%'", "");
}
    
console.log( replaceIt(44, 999) );
```